# middleman app it is possible to create a contact form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, contacts, middleman

I have a very basic question.

I have create a simple website with middleman app (a one page website) as portfolio.
Now I would like to add a simple contact form to allow user to contact the admin of the page with this logic:

the user use the contact form on the page

> >
>   the app check the inputs
>   >
>   the app create a message and send it to the admin mail box
>   >
>   the user receive a confirm message (also it is redirect to a new 'confirm' page)

I know it should be a simple thing to do and there are many tutorails about it, but I am new the rails and mvc logic...

Also on middleman I have no models or 'classic' files as in a rails app, and I am not so sure I could create a contact form on a static middleman app.

Anyone could help me? Or suggest me some specific gems to use or tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Remember that Middleman is a static site generator, but you'll need something dynamic in order to process the form. Pretty much anything will do: a simple PHP script, Rails/Sinatra app, etc., so long as it's running on a server. There are even services like [SimpleForm](http://getsimpleform.com/) which are pre-built for this purpose.

Once that's set up, simply point your form's action attribute to the address of the processing code. e.g.:

```
<form method="post" action="http://someserver.com/process_form">
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I begin to use/study Sinatra for creating something nice, because it seems more 'simple' then RoR.

so, no middleman app for dynamic and 'magic' stuff :)

Comment: is there a way to run both middleman and php on the same localhost?